# Question about downloading webpages using PHP

Tags: php, download

I am trying to download a bunch of webpages from this website:

http://community.giffgaff.com/

However, when I try to download the webpages, the webpages I downloaded using PHP and the ones I saw in browser are different. It seems that the ones that I downloaded missed a large part of the original one.

Thanks!

To be more specific, below is one webpage that I am trying to download:

http://community.giffgaff.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/120035

Out of the whole webpage, I am especially interested in the "My Recent Kudos Received" sesssion, but I can't find it anywhere in the source code of the webpage, or any link that direct me to other webpages containing related information.

The code I use for downloading is pretty basic, and it works well for other webpages.

```
<?php

$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$link) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

echo 'Connected successfully';}


function project($link)
{   
    set_time_limit(0);

    {
        $threadurl="http://community.giffgaff.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/120035";
        $lhandle=fopen($threadurl,'r');
        while(!feof($lhandle))
        {

            $gread=fgets($lhandle,4096);
            echo $gread;

        }
    }

}
project($link);


?>
```

Comment: It'd be great if you showed the code you've tried so far and explained more specifically what you're trying to accomplish. :)

Comment: if you want to download the page to display it somewhere else as if it was locally you have to download the html, any css files, any js files, all images, and even so it may give you some errors after that. **You have to be more specific about what you need to extract from that page and what you want to do with it.**

Comment: [None of these helped?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+download+webpage)

Comment: When I view the source, I most certainly see the `My Recent Kudos Received` section (line 873).

Comment: Do not complicate, just use `$c=file_get_contents($link);`

Comment: No. None of them talking about a similar situation.

Comment: I tried file_get_contents function. It gives me the same results as my code did

Comment: Yes, I see the "My Recent Kudos Received section (line 873)" when I look at the source code of that webpage if I open it in browser. But if I download it to local machine, and open it again, all those information is just gone.

Comment: I got it. If I add this line on top:ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9'); then i get exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The browser might check the signature of the browser, which performed the request - and send different output, e.g. for IE or iPhone mobile Webkit.

I just requested the page using PHP on MAMP on an iMac and using Safari. Seem to be different.